# select based on lookup table

Tags: mysql, sql, lookup-tables

I have following problem.
I want to select data from one table based on lookup table. This is the easy part. 
But in the results I want a new column which is based on the lookup table.

Here a example scenario:

```css
LOOKUP-TABLE
Account|Company|Area|origin|aktive
-----------------------------------
0020200|xqzComp|0100|HK1000|1
0020300|xyzComp|0100|HK2000|0
0020400|xxzComp|0100|HK3000|0
0020500|xbzComp|0100|HK4000|1


DATA-TABLE
Account|Company|Area|State|keyFig1|KeyFig2
-------------------------------------------
0020200|xqzComp|0100|GERM|100.000|200.000
0020400|xxzComp|0100|AUST|210.000|130.000
0020400|xxzComp|0100|GERM|222.000|111.000
0020500|xbzComp|0100|GERM|111.000|212.000


RESULT:
Account|Company|Area|State|keyFig1|KeyFig2|new column
------------------------------------------------------
0020200|xqzComp|0100|GERM|100.000|200.000 |is_HK100
0020500|xbzComp|0100|GERM|111.000|212.000 |not_HK100
```

The fields Account, Company, Area are all key-fields for the inner join.
But how to create the colum "new column" which is based in the column "origin" of the lookup table

Thank you very much!

Comment: What are the challenges you are facing? Please share whatever you have tried so far. What is the logic behind new_column data?

Answer (score 2):

```
select Account, Company, Area, State, keyFig1, KeyFig2,
    case 
        when table_2.origin = 'HK1000' then 'is_HK1000'
        else 'not_HK1000'
    end new_column
from table_1
inner join table_2
on table_1.Account = table_2.Account
     and table_1.Company= table_2.Company
     and table_1.Area = table_2.Area
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I forgot to mention that I use a "group by" in the select of the lookup table. I group on Account,Company and Area. So "origin" is not in the select statement. Unfortunately your code won't work if it is not in the select statement

Comment: In this case you can replace `inner join table_2` with `inner join (select whatever from whatever where whatever group by whatever) table_2`

Comment: I did it, but you can not use table_2.origin in the first select statement if you do not select it in the inner join. Unfortunately I do not select it because I do not use it in the "group by". I hope you understand my problem. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't use `origin` in `group by`, then how do you get lookup-table with `origin` in it? Could you show the code that selects it?

Comment: `select Account, Company, Area
from lookup
where Origin in ('HK1000', HK4000) and active = 1
group by Account, Company, Area` I need the Origin field only for selecting valid parameter